# JSON encode/decode Swift CNContact object generically

Tags: json, swift

I have been trying to JSON-encode/-decode Swift's `CNContact` object in a generic way (by that I mean that I want to determine what properties the object holds during runtime, I don't want to hard code its properties), however I didn't manage to do so. My question is: is there a way to achieve this behaviour in Swift 4 and if yes, how can this be done?

Comment: you want to multiple field in json from contact?

Comment: I want to serialize and deserialize all properties that every CNContact object holds... Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `CNContact` hasn't changed according to the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontact), so it doesn't conform to the `Codable` protocol, which is just a typealias for `Encodeable & Decodable`. You can see the list of classes currently conforming to [Encodable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/encodable) and [Decodable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable) and see here as well that `CNContact` is not amongst them.

However, you can write an extension for `CNContact` to make it conform to above protocols.

Here is an example of how to encode a `CNContact` object using `JSONSerialization` framework in `Swift3`. Please note that this is just an example, so I haven't parsed all possible fields and with this implementation if a certain value doesn't exist in the `CNContact` object, the key doesn't exist in the `JSON` either. Also, the decoder function is not implemented fully, but you can easily implement it if you check how the encoder works.

The names of the `JSON` keys were also chosen arbitrarily along with the structure, so you can change any of those.

Below piece of code is a full, working playground file, so you can test it yourself if you want to.

```
import Contacts

let contact = CNMutableContact()
contact.birthday = DateComponents(calendar: Calendar.current,year: 1887, month: 1, day: 1)
contact.contactType = CNContactType.person
contact.givenName = "John"
contact.familyName = "Appleseed"

contact.imageData = Data() // The profile picture as a NSData object

let homeEmail = CNLabeledValue(label:CNLabelHome, value: NSString(string: "john@example.com"))
let workEmail = CNLabeledValue(label:CNLabelWork, value: NSString(string: "j.appleseed@icloud.com"))
contact.emailAddresses = [homeEmail, workEmail]

contact.phoneNumbers = [CNLabeledValue(label:CNLabelPhoneNumberiPhone, value:CNPhoneNumber(stringValue:"(408) 555-0126"))]

let homeAddress = CNMutablePostalAddress()
homeAddress.street = "1 Infinite Loop"
homeAddress.city = "Cupertino"
homeAddress.state = "CA"
homeAddress.postalCode = "95014"
contact.postalAddresses = [CNLabeledValue(label:CNLabelHome, value:homeAddress)]

func encodeContactToJson(contact: CNContact)->Data?{
    var contactDict = [String:Any]()
    if let birthday = contact.birthday?.date {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        contactDict["birthday"] = df.string(from: birthday)
    }
    contactDict["givenName"] = contact.givenName
    contactDict["familyName"] = contact.familyName
    if let imageData = contact.imageData {
        contactDict["image"] = imageData.base64EncodedString()
    }
    if contact.emailAddresses.count > 0 {
        var emailAddresses = [String:String]()
        for (index, emailAddress) in contact.emailAddresses.enumerated() {
            emailAddresses[emailAddress.label ?? "email\(index)"] = (emailAddress.value as String)
        }
        contactDict["emailAddresses"] = emailAddresses
    }
    if contact.phoneNumbers.count > 0 {
        var phoneNumbers = [String:String]()
        for (index, phoneNumber) in contact.phoneNumbers.enumerated() {
            phoneNumbers[phoneNumber.label ?? "phone\(index)"] = phoneNumber.value.stringValue
        }
        contactDict["phoneNumbers"] = phoneNumbers
    }
    if contact.postalAddresses.count > 0 {
        var postalAddresses = [String:String]()
        for (index, postalAddress) in contact.postalAddresses.enumerated() {
            postalAddresses[postalAddress.label ?? "postal\(index)"] = (CNPostalAddressFormatter.string(from: postalAddress.value, style: .mailingAddress))
        }
        contactDict["postalAddresses"] = postalAddresses
    }
    return try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: contactDict)
}

func decodeContactsJson(jsonData: Data)->CNContact?{
    if let jsonDict = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData)) as? [String:Any] {
        let contact = CNMutableContact()
        print(jsonDict)
        return contact as CNContact
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

if let jsonContact = encodeContactToJson(contact: contact) {
    print(decodeContactsJson(jsonData: jsonContact) ?? "Decoding failed")
} else {
    print("Encoding failed")
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am not at all experienced with Swift development, can you provide a sample code of such an extension for CNContact?

Comment: I don't currently have Xcode9 beta installed, so I can't compile `Swift4` code and I don't want to provide you a code sample that might not compile. However, if you want, I can give you a small sample of how to do it using the `JSONSerialization` framework, which is already available in `Swift3`.

Comment: I would really appreciate that :)

Comment: @mmarkus check out my updated answer, I have included a full working example

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Simple with contact pick.

```
func contactViewController(_ viewController: CNContactViewController, didCompleteWith contact: CNContact?) {

    var name = ""
    var email = ""
    var mobile =  ""
    var address = ""
    var companyname = ""
    var jobtitle = ""
    var organization = ""
    var workaddress = ""
    var worknumber = ""
    var personalurl = ""
    var companyurl = ""
    var otherurl = ""
    var othernumber = ""
    var otheraddress = ""
    var homeemail = ""
    var workemail = ""
    var otheremail = ""
    var dataAll = NSMutableArray()

    if contact != nil
    {
        dataAll = NSMutableArray()



        if (contact?.isKeyAvailable(CNContactGivenNameKey))! {
            let name2 = contact?.familyName
            name = (contact?.givenName)! + " " + name2!

            UserDefaults.standard.set(name, forKey: "name")


        }



        if (contact?.isKeyAvailable(CNContactOrganizationNameKey))!
        {
            companyname  = (contact?.organizationName)!


            //var dic : NSDictionary = [:]
            if companyname != "" {
                let dic : [String : AnyObject] = ["name":companyname as AnyObject,
                                                  "type":"companyname" as AnyObject,
                                                  "typeof":"companyname" as AnyObject]
                dataAll.add(dic)
            }



        }

        let designation = contact?.jobTitle

        if (designation?.isEmpty)!
        {

        }
        else
        {
            jobtitle = designation!
            //let dic : [String : AnyObject] = ["designation":jobtitle as AnyObject]

            let dic : [String : AnyObject] = ["name":jobtitle as AnyObject,
                                              "type":"designation" as AnyObject,
                                              "typeof":"designation" as AnyObject
            ]
            dataAll.add(dic)

        }
        if (contact?.isKeyAvailable(CNContactPhoneNumbersKey))!{

            if (contact?.phoneNumbers.count == 0)
            {

            }
            else
            {

                for phoneNumber:CNLabeledValue in (contact?.phoneNumbers)! {
                    let number  = phoneNumber.value

                    let number2 = number.stringValue


                    let lable :String  =  CNLabeledValue<NSString>.localizedString(forLabel: phoneNumber.label! )


                    let dic : [String : AnyObject] = ["name":number2 as AnyObject,
                                                      "type":lable as AnyObject,
                                                      "typeof":"phonenumber" as AnyObject]


                    dataAll.add(dic)


                    if number2 != ""
                    {

                    }


                    if lable == "home"
                    {
                        if number2 == ""
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mobile = number.stringValue


                            let number2  = String(mobile.digitsOnly())!



                        }


                    }
                    if lable == "work"
                    {
                        if number2 == ""
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            worknumber = number.stringValue

                        }


                    }
                    if lable == "mobile"
                    {
                        if number2 == ""
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            othernumber = number.stringValue


                        }


                    }

                }

            }
        }


        if (contact?.isKeyAvailable(CNContactEmailAddressesKey))! {

            if (contact?.emailAddresses.count == 0)
            {

            }
            else
            {

                for emaiadd:CNLabeledValue in (contact?.emailAddresses)! {

                    let name2 = (emaiadd.value as String) as String

                    if name2 != ""
                    {
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(emaiadd.value as String, forKey: "mainemail")
                    }

                    let lable :String  =  CNLabeledValue<NSString>.localizedString(forLabel: emaiadd.label! )

                    //  let dic : [String : AnyObject] = [lable:emaiadd.value as String as AnyObject]
                    let dic : [String : AnyObject] = ["name":name2 as AnyObject,
                                                      "type":lable as AnyObject,
                                                      "typeof":"email" as AnyObject]

                    dataAll.add(dic)


                    if lable == "home"
                    {

                        if name2 == ""
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            email = emaiadd.value as String


                        }

                    }
                    if lable == "work"
                    {
                        if name2 == ""
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            workemail = emaiadd.value as String

                        }

                    }
                    if lable == "other"
                    {
                        if name2 == ""
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            otheremail = emaiadd.value as String

                        }

                    }

                }
            }

        }



        if (contact?.isKeyAvailable(CNContactPostalAddressesKey))! {

            for addres:CNLabeledValue in (contact?.postalAddresses)! {

                let addre = addres.value
                let addre2 = addre.street

                let lable :String  =  CNLabeledValue<NSString>.localizedString(forLabel: addres.label! )


                let dic : [String : AnyObject] = ["name":addre2 as AnyObject,
                                                  "type":lable as AnyObject,
                                                  "typeof":"address" as AnyObject]

                dataAll.add(dic)

                if lable == "home"
                {
                    if addre2 == ""
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        address = addre.street



                    }
                }

                if lable == "work"
                {
                    if addre2 == ""
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        workaddress = addre.street

                    }

                }
                if lable == "other"
                {
                    if addre2 == ""
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        otheraddress = addre.street


                    }
                }

                print(lable + (addre.street))
            }


        }

        if (contact?.isKeyAvailable(CNContactUrlAddressesKey))! {

            for urladd:CNLabeledValue in (contact?.urlAddresses)! {

                let url2 = (urladd.value as String) as String

                let lable :String  =  CNLabeledValue<NSString>.localizedString(forLabel: urladd.label! )


                let dic : [String : AnyObject] = ["name":url2 as AnyObject,
                                                  "type":lable as AnyObject,
                                                  "typeof":"url" as AnyObject]

                dataAll.add(dic)

                if lable == "home"
                {
                    if url2 == ""
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        personalurl = urladd.value as String



                    }
                }
                if lable == "work"
                {
                    if url2 == ""
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        companyurl = urladd.value as String


                    }

                }
                if lable == "other"
                {
                    if url2 == ""
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        otherurl = urladd.value as String



                    }

                }


            }

        }

        if (contact?.isKeyAvailable(CNContactImageDataKey))! {

            let image = contact?.imageData

            let utf8str = image?.base64EncodedString()


        }



        dataArr = [["code": "Mobile", "title": othernumber],["code": "Work Number", "title": worknumber],["code": "OtherMobile", "title": number2],["code": "Email", "title": email],["code": "WorkEmail", "title": workemail],["code": "OtherEmail", "title": otheremail],["code": "Address", "title": address],["code": "Work Address", "title": workaddress],["code": "OtherAddress", "title": otheraddress],["code": "Company Name", "title": companyname],["code": "Designation", "title": jobtitle],["code": "Personal Website", "title": personalurl],["code": "Company Website", "title": companyurl],["code": "Other Website", "title": otherurl]]
    }

}
```

Add this code in button action

```
 let contactPickerViewController = CNContactPickerViewController()

        contactPickerViewController.delegate = self

        present(contactPickerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: When working with Swift if possible, avoid using Foundation versions of data structures that have native Swift alternatives (such as `NSMutableArray`, you should use `Array<Type>`). Also, you should reformat your code, since it is extremely hard to read with all the unnecessary whitespaces. Your answer doesn't actually answer the question, since you only return a dictionary, not an actual `JSON` object and in the question there was no mention of the `CNContactPickerViewController`.